# Create Follow up Task using PB/WF

Tags: workflow, process-builder, tasks

Is it possible to do this using process builder or workflow ? follow up task must be created if my old task(related to account or contact or lead) was not yet completed in 1 week.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a time dependent workflow and use a custom field to store created date of old task.